# File path/name under Databricks file system

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use glob function glob to grab directory/file name under regular Python.

For example:

```py
glob.glob("/dbfs/mnt/.../*/A*.txt")
```

However, just realized under DBFS, the full path name starts with /mnt. But is there a way under Pyspark like using glob to get the file directory/name list?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to get directory/name list, you can only do it in Python.
Pyspark can process a directory/name list `sc.textFile("/dbfs/mnt/.../*/A*.txt")`, but not return it.

Pyspark is a processing engine, not a framework for filesystem tasks.

Comment: I actually have flat files sitting in different location and would like to use pyspark's function spark.read.load to loop each of them to create a big master spark dataframe. That's why I ask this question. Do you know if there is a possible way of loop through each folder to get the file path?

Comment: @YiDu the answer is simple.. You can use Python to create a list with all the  fullpaths of the files and then use this list as parameter in spark read. It will works :-)